# Severity: Warning Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a dynamic select ? which carries the values ​​in another select . Charging is running . However displays this Message:

**Severity: Warning  Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  Filename: helpers/form_helper.php**

This is my controller:

```
 public function getparcelas()
{   if($this->input->post('aquiller'))
    {
        $parcelas = $this->input->post('aquiller');
        $localidades = $this->sindico->get_parcelas($parcelas);
            foreach($localidades as $fila)
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?=$fila->numero_parcelas ?>"><?=$fila->numero_parcelas ?></option>
            <?php
        }
    }
}}
```

My view : This is my view

```
 $dados['album'] = $this->sindico->get_aquiller();
    echo "<select name='aquiller' id='aquiller' class='form-control input-sm'>";
    if (count($dados['album'])) {
        foreach ($dados['album'] as $list) {
            echo "<option value='". $list['id_alug'] . "'>" . $list['numero_apart'] . "-" . $list['nome_usu'] . "</option>";

        }
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo form_dropdown('localidad', '', '', 'class="localidad" id="localidad"');
```

This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#somar").click(function(){
            var total = 0;
            $('.input').each(function(){
                var valor = Number($(this).val());
                if (!isNaN(valor)) total += valor;
            });
            $(".resultado").val(total.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    function calcular(){
        var dt1 = document.getElementById("dt1").value;
        var dt2 = document.getElementById("dt2").value;

        var data1 = new Date(dt1);
        var data2 = new Date(new Date(dt2));
        var total = (data2.getFullYear() - data1.getFullYear())*12 + (data2.getMonth() - data1.getMonth());
        document.getElementById("result").value = total;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this code? echo form_dropdown('localidad', '', '', 'class="localidad" id="localidad"');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem lies in *form_helper.php* means this line of code calling it.

```
echo form_dropdown('localidad', '', '', 'class="localidad" id="localidad"');
```

Now this function **form_dropdown** expect one parameter to be an array. It could be 2nd or third. Make sure you have read documentation to this function.

Comment: I believe also that the problem is in form_dropdown . can you help me?

Comment: paste the code of this function from helper file. paste it your question only.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried debugging to check what exactly is the content of this $dados['album']? Maybe it doesn't have any index 'id_alug' or 'numero_apart'.

Try this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dados['album']);     // Add this

if (count($dados['album'])) { 
    .........
}
```

Let me know what you get after doing print_r.

Comment: friend most certainly is not it. For I took all of it and the error keeps popping up . I believe the error is in the controller .